# Function that adds one to each numeric value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

> Write a function that adds one to each numeric value in a dictionary. If the value is not numeric (i.e. not an int or float), don't add anything, but keep the same value. The function should take a dictionary as argument, and return the modified dictionary.
>
> Pay particular attention to looping through keys and values in dictionaries using items(). The pattern to use with "items()" is this:

```
for key, value in mydict.items():


    
    def addtovalue(dictionary):
    "Add one to each numeric value of the dictionary, return the dict"
    
    # TYPE YOUR CODE HERE.
    
    dictionary = { 'fred': 3.3, 'marie': '5', 'jean': 14, 'angus': 44, 'amine': 'blue'}
    
    for k,v in dictionary.items():

        if v is not float or int:
            print(v)
        else:
            new_v = v + 1
            print(new_v)
```

This is what I've got so far, but it is not working. I'm a beginner. How do I modify all values in a dictionary at once?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing so far is `isinstance` for checking types, i.e.

```
if not (isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float)):
```

As far as the actual value assignment goes, you could do something like:

```
dictionary[k] = new_v
```

or

```
dictionary.update({k: new_v})
```

Also, you may already realize this, but for your code to be included in the function you'll need to indent the code you want in the function. In the end, this may look something like:

```
def addtovalue(dictionary):
    "Add one to each numeric value of the dictionary, return the dict"

    for k,v in dictionary.items():

        if not (isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float)):
            print(v)
        else:
            new_v = v + 1
            print(new_v)
            dictionary[k] = new_v

    return dictionary
```

which you can call with something like:

```
dictionary = { 'fred': 3.3, 'marie': '5', 'jean': 14, 'angus': 44, 'amine': 'blue'}
addtovalue(dictionary)
# {'fred': 4.3, 'marie': '5', 'jean': 15, 'angus': 45, 'amine': 'blue'}
```

and which, as @Jonas Palačionis pointed out, you can simplify this into something like:

```
def addtovalue(dictionary):
    "Add one to each numeric value of the dictionary, return the dict"

    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        if (isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float)):
            dictionary.update({k: v+1})

    return dictionary
```

You could simplify even more than that using a dictionary comprehension and `numbers.Number`, like @rasjani pointed out, like this:

```
import numbers

def addtovalue(dictionary):
    "Add one to each numeric value of the dictionary, return the dict"
    dictionary.update({k: v+1 
                       for (k,v) in d.items() 
                       if isinstance(v, numbers.Number)})
    return dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't "modify all the values in a dictionary at once", you modify them key by key. And the simple way to modify the value for a given key is quite simply to assign the value to the key:

```
d = {"a":1, "b": 2}
d["a"] = 42
print(d)
```

So what you want here is, instead of printing out the updated values, to update the dict itself.

A couple other things:

```
if v is not float or int:
```

is doubly wrong. First, to typecheck a variable, you don't do an identity test against a type, you use either `isinstance(var, cls)` (recommended) or `type(var) is cls` (if you really want to restrict the test to the exact class). Then, the expression "x == y or z" doesn't compare "x" with "y", then with "z". It's evaluated as "(x == y) or (z)", which is totally different:

```
>>> x = 42
>>> x == 33 or 22
22
>>> x == 42 or 22
True
>>> x == 22 or 42
42
>>>
```

IOW you have to write explicit comparisons:

```
>>> x == 22 or x == 42
True
>>> x == 42 or x == 22
True
>>> x == 33 or x == 22
False
>>>
```

And finally, re-read your specs, they explicitly tell you that 1/ you should be working on the dict that is passed to your function and 2/ that you should return the modified dict from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
dictionary = {'fred': 3.3, 'marie': '5',
              'jean': 14, 'angus': 44, 'amine': 'blue'}


def new_dict(my_dict):
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if (isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float)):
            my_dict.update({k: v+1})

    return my_dict


print(new_dict(dictionary))
```

```
{'fred': 4.3, 'marie': '5', 'jean': 15, 'angus': 45, 'amine': 'blue'}
```

You iterate through your dictionary and check if the value of each pair is either `int` or `float` and if so, you update the value of that key by adding 1 using `.update({k,v+1})`

And your task asks you to write a function, you are not writing a function.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably way more efficient and easier to read solutions but dict comprehension could be used to generate separate dict that has all numeric values updated and then that new dict can be updated into the existing one:

```
import numbers
d = { 'fred': 3.3, 'marie': '5', 'jean': 14, 'angus': 44, 'amine': 'blue'}
d.update({ k: v+1 for (k,v) in d.items() if isinstance(v, numbers.Number) })
```

and result looks like:

```
>>> print(d)
{'fred': 4.3, 'marie': '5', 'jean': 15, 'angus': 45, 'amine': 'blue'}
>>>
```